# How can I change the timeframe for EMA-2 based on timeframe of EMA-1 automatically in Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create script where the timeframe for 2nd EMA is selected based on the timeframe of first EMA.

e.g. if the the current timeframe is 1 Minute then for first the EMA, the script will use the current timeframe and for second EMA, the script will use the 2 Minute timeframe, and similarly for the third EMA, the script will use 3 Minute timeframe.

I am struggling to the script to automatically select the higher timeframes based. here is the code I have created. Would appreciate if anyone can help me how to fix this.

thanks

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='MTF EMA', shorttitle='MTF EMA', overlay=true, format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe='')


////////////

// Input Time Frames
hmaRes1M = input.timeframe(title='Time Frame 1', defval='')
hmaRes2M = input.timeframe(title='Time Frame 2', defval='')

hmaResHTF1 = input.timeframe(title='HTF1', defval='') 
hmaResHTF2 = input.timeframe(title='HTF2', defval='')

//

if timeframe.period==hmaRes1M
    hmaResHTF1==hmaRes2M

if timeframe.period==hmaRes1M
    hmaResHTF2==hmaRes3M

////

if timeframe.period==hmaRes2M
    hmaResHTF1==hmaRes4M

if timeframe.period==hmaRes2M
    hmaResHTF2==hmaRes6M


//ema1
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 300)
plot(ema1, color=color.new(#7E169E, 0), linewidth=3, title='ema1') 

//ema2
ema2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, hmaResHTF1, ema1)
plot(org1, color=color.new(#FF6CAB, 0), linewidth=2, title='ema2', style=plot.style_cross) 

//ema3
ema3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, hmaResHTF2, ema1)
plot(org2, color=color.new(#00F7FF, 0), linewidth=2, title='ema3', style=plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it your way, you have to make `hmaResHTF1` and `hmaResHTF2` a variable of type string. In the if's, you have to set them to a specific other string. This can't be done through `==`, because `==` is a language operator, which returns a boolean.

If you want to set a variable, you have to use `:=`.

Timeframes are always a string.

I don't really want to do it that way, because I think there are two much simpler solutions.

In case you want to calculate it automatically, there is a variable from pine-script: `timeframe.multiplier`, which gets the multiplier of the current timeframe. Considering you're in the 4 minutes timeframe, the `timeframe.multiplier` would be `4`.

So you could code it like this:

```
current_timeframe = timeframe.multiplier

// ema1
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 300)
plot(ema1, color=color.new(#7E169E, 0), linewidth=3, title='1. Ema')

//ema2
ema2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(current_timeframe+1), ema1) // current_timeframe + 1 -> then to string --> from '1' to '2'
plot(ema2, color=color.new(#FF6CAB, 0), linewidth=2, title='2. Ema', style=plot.style_cross) 

//ema3
ema3 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring(current_timeframe+2), ema1)  // current_timeframe + 2 -> then to string --> from '1' to '3'
plot(ema3, color=color.new(#00F7FF, 0), linewidth=2, title='3. Ema', style=plot.style_cross)
```

Personally, I don't really like the `request.security()` function. This is where the second option comes in.

Let's say we are in the 1-minute timeframe. The 300-Ema is the ema out of 300 bars, right? So the 300-Ema of the 2-minute timeframe is 300-2 minute-bars, or rather 600-1 minute-bars.

```
current_timeframe = timeframe.multiplier
len = input.int(300, title="Ema Length")

// ema1
ema1 = ta.ema(close, len)
plot(ema1, color=color.new(#7E169E, 0), linewidth=3, title='1. Ema')

//ema2
ema2 = ta.ema(close, len*2)
plot(ema2, color=color.new(#FF6CAB, 0), linewidth=2, title='2. Ema', style=plot.style_cross) 

//ema3
ema3 = ta.ema(close, len*3)
plot(ema3, color=color.new(#00F7FF, 0), linewidth=2, title='3. Ema', style=plot.style_cross)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you gave a perfect solution. really appreciate that :)

Comment: is it possible to to plot a moving average for more than 5000 bars somehow?